# Context.getExternalFilesDirs(null) is not defined

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying `context.getExternalFilesDirs(null)` to get paths for mounted storages. I intend to use this method keeping in view the new restrictions imposed by android in Kitkat. When I write statement to make a call to the method it gets underlined in RED with message as shown in image below:

[image]

I have checked all installations required to support API level 19 and everything seems fine.
[image]

My application is targeted for API 19 with minimum sdk version set to 16.
[image]

I have checked it a lot and looks like no one has faced this issue. I don't know what can possibly go wrong here but if you have any idea that where I am doing wrong please identify. Thank you

Comment: try it after setting `android:maxSdkVersion="19"`

Comment: I dont think that method is supposed to take `null`.

Comment: First null should not be passed, second try clean building the project as this is not a common thing to happen.

Comment: can you post the manifest ? Also remove the images and post the   code causing your issue

Comment: I was missing the basic here. Error was resolved by changing the project build version to 4.4.2. Thank you all :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I resolved the above issue.Right side click on  **Project -> Properties -> Android -> *set Project Build Target to* > Android 4.4.2 -> Apply**

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String)) ,

```
getExternalFilesDirs()
```

has been added with API 19, and your min SDK is 16, you have to check that when you run on devices less than API 19 and there by organize your functionalities.You can Use TargetAPI annotation and then red underline will be removed.